# Building a Quote Database without Server Side

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, quotes, business-catalyst

I want to build a searchable database of quotes. The idea is I would type in a keyword to a search box and I would have quotes with those keywords. I would assign key words to the quotes. I am using a hosted CMS (Adobe Business Catalyst) and cannot use server side scripting. How is the best way to go about this? Is it possible to do this with javascript and jquery?

Comment: The FAQ for Adobe Bus. Catalyst says "You'll have an FTP account to upload web pages, CSS, flash, JavaScript and images."  Is that an option?  Maybe they provide hooks or custom tags to access the data you're after.

Comment: Put your quotes in as static array of objects, as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441555/how-can-i-assign-static-pieces-of-information-to-randomly-selected-data-with-jav/10441618#10441618.  Then when the user triggers a search, iterate over your array for matches and display them as necessary.  This could get slow if your "database of quotes" gets large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put all of the quotes on to the page statically in a JSON object, or even just as HTML elements, ready to be shown, but hidden. Then search through them with your keywords, and un-hide the ones that are relevant to the search.

Depending on how many quotes you have, the page could become large and take a long time to load, but that's just something to keep in mind for performance.

Comment: This is what I was thinking too. A JSON string or pre-defined array. You could store it in a separate file and import it so you won't have to look at it every time you edit your code.

Comment: I thought of that but that would get cumbersome but might be the best solution.

Comment: It would be a little cumbersome, but since it has to work all client side, you don't have a lot of options unfortunately. If you wanted to get another hosting account, you could use it as a kind of API to search from this Adobe CMS site, but I figured that was going outside your requirements set in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about doing this is build a quotes web app. Then construct a web apps search form and only include a text box for searching by keyword. BC will automatically search the description of the item or the custom field in your web app, whichever you choose.

This WILL take less time than creating JSON objects are parsing HTML code. This utilizes server side logic and only returns to the browser the results that match your criteria so this will have better performance.

The only downside is the results page will not be SEO friendly. In the case where you want to create a pre-defined search, I would Ajax in the results of the search into your static page.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research I discovered that Business Catalyst will allow you to build ["Web Apps"](http://kb.worldsecuresystems.com/868/cpsid_86860.html?bc-partner). This can operate as a database and you can incorporate a nice search into the webapp that will allow you to search for keywords etc.

Other than that I believe you would be required to follow @ctcherry 's method.